# How did Nachiketa travel to Yamaloka?

Tags: yama, yamaloka

Is there is any descriptions about how Nachiketa's  journey to YamaLoka in Upanishad or in Purana's.

Descriptions like how many day's he took to reach YamaLoka would be appreciated.

Comment: The Katha Upanishad, which contains the story of Nachiketa, did not mention as to how he performed his journey to the abode of Yama.